# Install ubuntu minimal desktop and configure basic commands

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I want to install very minimal version of ubuntu on my pc, which understand my input output devices (keyboard, mouse, microphone, speaker) and basic ubuntu commends (e.g. apt-get) but no extra things like GUI, open jdk, firefox etc.

Then I want to install some basic software like google-chrome, Intellij IDEA, smart git etc, which need GUI, But I don't want any file explorer. Because, I want to practice my commands more.

Then I want to write some script, like for start all dev tools which start all applications which are needed for development, like intellej, smart git, browser etc.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: Also, you need OpenJDK (or a compatible JDK) to run IntelliJ.

Comment: You may find the Ubuntu Forums better for a longer dialogue, https://ubuntuforums.org

Answer (score 2):

You can start with either an Ubuntu [**mini.iso**](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13211730#post13211730) or an **Ubuntu Server** iso file. Install a minimal system.

Boot into the minimal system, and use **apt-get** to install the program packages you want. You may prefer a simple window manager, for example **fluxbox** or **openbox** (instead of a full desktop environment, for example Unity, KDE, LXDE, XFCE). You probably need **xinit** and **xterm** too as a starter for the graphics. The graphics is started with

```
startx
```

from the text screen.

Comment: A window manager you may want to use after following these steps is i3-wm. It's a tiling window manager centered around terminal use, but will allow you to use GUI applications too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Ubuntu Mini Remix'. It has only Command Line Interface(CLI). You can use it with virtual box or with live CD or pendrive.

After booting the OS you have to put the username 'ubuntu' and password should be blank, simply hit the enter key.

[image: login_page]

After the login it looks like this.
[image: after_login]

It uses so little memory (mine is 21mb) that you can use it on any old system.

[image: ram_usage]

To check the ram uses, use this command:

> free -m

You can shutdown the system with the following command:

> sudo shutdown -h now

To restart the OS use this command:

> sudo shutdown -r now

You can download 'Ubuntu Mini Remix' from [here](http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/)

This is a **live operating system**, so it will not ask you to install it in your hard disk. But you can install it manually with [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix/+faq/35) guide.

But if you want to installed the system in your hard disk, I will recommend you to install 'ubuntu mini' without any desktop environment like Gnome,XFCE,Mate,KDE etc (It will ask you to choose the desktop environment while installing the OS). You can download Ubuntu Mini from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). 
Remember, **you need an active internet connection while installing 'Ubuntu Mini'**. So you can not install Ubuntu Mini offline.

It is best to install 'Ubuntu Server' if you want to install the system offline and you want to install the OS inside of your hard disk. You can install Ubuntu Server from [this](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) link.