# Is there an Ubuntu CLI only installation with GUI/$DISPLAY support?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gui

I have the NetBoot/Minimal installer currently booted on my system, and I'm in the "Software Selection" screen. Is there a way to install the CLI with access to the `$DISPLAY` variable? I've read something about X server, but I'm not sure what this is.

**NOTE:** for anyone wondering, I *do not* understand the concept at all, I'm still new to all this Ubuntu stuff.

Comment: See one of these links: [Install ubuntu minimal desktop and configure basic commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863713/install-ubuntu-minimal-desktop-and-configure-basic-commands/863717#863717) and [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - how is the X server started?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937097/ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-is-the-x-server-started/987945#987945)

Comment: What are your intentions with the DISPLAY variable? I am not getting beyond the idea you are not understanding the concept. "Is there an Ubuntu CLI only installation with GUI/$DISPLAY support?" When you have a GUI that does not mean you can not have a CLI system. All this means you do not boot into the desktop. That is a setting, it is the config of each version that is slightly different but all have the same packages available. When you have a system with lightdm desktop `sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service` will disable booting into it and you will end up with a normal login prompt.

Comment: @Rinzwind you are correct in thinking that I do not understand the concept. That's what I've been trying to figure out for the past few days. XD

Comment: @sudodus I wish I knew that before I formatted the hard drive... XD

Comment: Now you know. Good luck :-)